# R tidyverse: create groups based on index column

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have this tibble

```
# Data
set.seed(1)
x <- tibble(values = round(rnorm(20, 10, 10), 0),
            index = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
                      1,1,0,0,0))
x
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>    values index
#>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1      4     0
#>  2     12     0
#>  3      2     1
#>  4     26     1
#>  5     13     1
#>  6      2     0
#>  7     15     1
#>  8     17     0
#>  9     16     1
#> 10      7     1
#> 11     25     1
#> 12     14     1
#> 13      4     1
#> 14    -12     1
#> 15     21     0
#> 16     10     1
#> 17     10     1
#> 18     19     0
#> 19     18     0
#> 20     16     0
```

I'd like to create groups where the value in the index column are consecutive ones. The final aim is to compute the sum per each group.

This is the expected tibble is someting like:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   values index group
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1      4     0 NA   
 2     12     0 NA   
 3      2     1 A    
 4     26     1 A    
 5     13     1 A    
 6      2     0 NA   
 7     15     1 B    
 8     17     0 NA   
 9     16     1 C    
10      7     1 C    
11     25     1 C    
12     14     1 C    
13      4     1 C    
14    -12     1 C    
15     21     0 NA   
16     10     1 D    
17     10     1 D    
18     19     0 NA   
19     18     0 NA   
20     16     0 NA
```

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `cumsum()` on runs identified by `rle()`, replacing the values where index is zero with `NA`.  If there are more than 26 IDs it will need a minor modification.

```
library(dplyr)

x2 <- x %>%
  mutate(id = LETTERS[replace(with(rle(index),
                                   rep(cumsum(values), lengths)), index == 0, NA)])
```

Giving:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   values index id   
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1      4     0 NA   
 2     12     0 NA   
 3      2     1 A    
 4     26     1 A    
 5     13     1 A    
 6      2     0 NA   
 7     15     1 B    
 8     17     0 NA   
 9     16     1 C    
10      7     1 C    
11     25     1 C    
12     14     1 C    
13      4     1 C    
14    -12     1 C    
15     21     0 NA   
16     10     1 D    
17     10     1 D    
18     19     0 NA   
19     18     0 NA   
20     16     0 NA
```

To sum the values:

```
x2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(sv = sum(values))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  id       sv
* <chr> <dbl>
1 A        41
2 B        15
3 C        54
4 D        20
5 NA      109
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, group :=  LETTERS[as.integer(factor((NA^!index) *rleid(index)))]]
x
#    values index group
# 1:      4     0  <NA>
# 2:     12     0  <NA>
# 3:      2     1     A
# 4:     26     1     A
# 5:     13     1     A
# 6:      2     0  <NA>
# 7:     15     1     B
# 8:     17     0  <NA>
# 9:     16     1     C
#10:      7     1     C
#11:     25     1     C
#12:     14     1     C
#13:      4     1     C
#14:    -12     1     C
#15:     21     0  <NA>
#16:     10     1     D
#17:     10     1     D
#18:     19     0  <NA>
#19:     18     0  <NA>
#20:     16     0  <NA>
```

---

Or similar logic in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  mutate(group = LETTERS[as.integer(factor((NA^!index) *rleid(index)))])
# A tibble: 20 x 3
#   values index group
#    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1      4     0 <NA> 
# 2     12     0 <NA> 
# 3      2     1 A    
# 4     26     1 A    
# 5     13     1 A    
# 6      2     0 <NA> 
# 7     15     1 B    
# 8     17     0 <NA> 
# 9     16     1 C    
#10      7     1 C    
#11     25     1 C    
#12     14     1 C    
#13      4     1 C    
#14    -12     1 C    
#15     21     0 <NA> 
#16     10     1 D    
#17     10     1 D    
#18     19     0 <NA> 
#19     18     0 <NA> 
#20     16     0 <NA>
```